# Is it possible for the average of 2 sets of numbers to be higher than the average of the combined set?

Tags: average

Say I have 2 sets of numbers with an equal number of values:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

Is it possible for `mean(a,b,c,d,e,f)` to be significantly lower than `mean(mean(a,b,c),mean(d,e,f))`? I have 2 large data sets where this is happening and I need to know whether it's possible or I made an error.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Well, $2\times 3=6$ so the averages are indeed equal...

Comment: It is possible if the two series are of unequal size. Say, the average of $(0,0,1)$ is $1/3$, while the averages of $(0,0)$ and $(1)$ are $0$ and $1$, respectively, and *their* average is $1/2$. However, if the series are of the same size, it cannot happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible (for the arithmetic mean).

Take the two tuples $x = (x_1,...,x_n),y=(y_1,...,y_n)$, then the question amounts to if :

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\sum_{i=1}^ny_i}{2n} = \frac{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n}+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i}{n}}{2}$$

This is clearly the case by simple calculations for fractions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the two series are of unequal size. Say, the average of $(0,0,1)$ is $1/3$, while the averages of $(0,0)$ and $(1)$ are $0$ and $1$, respectively, and *their* average is $1/2$. However, if the series are of the same size, it cannot happen (as proven in the other answer here, by @linkja).